# Drawing to canvas on click clears text when mouse leaves the chart

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I have a ChartJS doughnut chart that I would like to click on a segment and it displays information about the segment in the centre of the chart. I have got this working, however whenever the mouse leaves the chart segment the information disappears, I want it to stay until another chart segment is clicked.

I have put a basic example of this on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fa7s5q30/6/)

```
canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
    var activePoints = donut.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
    if(activePoints[0]) {
        var chartData = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
        var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];
        var label = chartData.labels[idx].toUpperCase();

        ctx.font = "bold 18px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif";
        var textWidth = ctx.measureText(label).width;

        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fillText(label, (250/2) - (textWidth/2), (250/2));
    }
};
```

How can I maintain the text in the centre of the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't draw to the canvas directly (as it's managed by Chart.js) use [plugin api](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) instead. You can use one of the hooks provided - for example `afterDraw` to draw your stuff after the chart was drawn.

Working JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fa7s5q30/12/

Comment: Can you get that working in the jsfiddle? I've tried and nothing is different (https://jsfiddle.net/fa7s5q30/7/). Moving all the code to `afterDraw` gives https://jsfiddle.net/fa7s5q30/8/.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer. `afterDraw` is called every time the chart is repainted (which is also on mouse move), so you need to store the selected label somewhere, otherwise it'd be cleared. I chose to attach it to the chart instance.

Comment: That works great in Chrome, but it doesn't display the chart in IE11. Doesn't flag any issues in the debugger either. Any way round that?

Comment: It's because of the object function shorthands not being suported https://jsfiddle.net/fa7s5q30/13/

Comment: That's it! Cheers.